# Where is the setting in Chrome/FireFox on Windows 10 the changes download prompt timing behavior?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, file-download

We have two different PCs running Chrome 63, FireFox 57 and Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. When "Ask where to save each file before downloading" has been turned on, Machine A immediately brings up a prompt when a download begins, Machine B downloads the entire file, then brings up the same prompt.

When that setting is turned off, Machine A shows the file download progress in a bar at the bottom of the browser window. Machine B downloads the entire file, THEN shows the download in the bottom of the browser window as fully downloaded.

This behavior is essentially identical in FireFox and Chrome leading me to wonder if this is some OS-level setting.

**This is NOT the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" option found in Settings->Advanced->Downloads.**

[image]

This is a youtube video that attempts to demonstrate the behavior from a screen capture I ran: https://youtu.be/xApCXRCJze8 Unfortunately, it does not show the popup window from the browser, but you can see what timing issues I'm describing here.

Comment: ...considering Firefox generally doesn't show downloaded files at the bottom, I'd like to see a screenshot. Better yet, a video capture if you can manage it (e.g. with ScreenToGif).

Comment: What do you have for `chrome://settings/`, Downloads section? Do the two  computers use identical Internet settings, or does the weird one go through a caching proxy?

Comment: What are your AV settings on each machine?

Comment: Let me know if reinstalling Firefox helps?

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to fix this just for myself, but rather that I need to understand this behavior so I can code around it as a developer. Asking my users to reinstall browsers isn't really going to solve my problem. We have multiple devices at the office that exhibit this behavior.

Comment: @RobbieCrash makes a good point with antivirus... some of them will intercept requests and download the full file before passing it on to the browser. It's terrible, broken behaviour but that describes just about everything your typical antivirus does anyway. You can check if your requests are being intercepted by using an HTTPS connection and comparing the certificate fingerprints (and issuers) received.

Comment: I hadn't thought of my anti-virus getting in the way, that would explain a lot though. Thanks, I'll let you know if I find anything interesting.

Comment: What do you have for `chrome://settings/`, Downloads section? Do the two computers use identical Internet settings, or does the weird one go through a caching proxy?